Classic ASP User Login in Windows 2003 server
I have a Classic ASP application running from Windows 2003 server which I am moving to Windows 2022 server. I have configured the application and the login page is loading. But post submitting it is trying to create a server object where it is failing. I see a registry entry for the object that code is using, but I do not know where the dll or installable file is location. How do I get this information.

This should help - Error ASP 0177: 8007007e CreateObject fails for COM DLL. But ideally [edit] the question and include the actual error that is happening.

Is there more detailed error information? For example, the error code. You can also enable Detailed errors message in IIS Error Pages settings, this should help for narrow down the issue.

Follow that check list and you can't go wrong, covers what to check and in what order. Also there's a detailed explanation of how to locate the DLL associated with a CreateObject() method call.
